# How to emit two separate documents concurrently in CouchDB?

Tags: javascript, couchdb, view, map-function, nosql

In CouchDB I would like to concurrently emit an object of type `country` and of type `city`. Is this possible in just one function?

Via Linked Documents I can emit an object value which is `{_id:doc.xxx}` like so:

```
function(doc) {
    if (doc.cities) {
        for (var i in doc.cities) {
            emit(doc.name, {_id: doc.cities[i]});
        }          
    }               
}
```

The function down below is my suggestions but it's not working because the second if-part will be never reached.

```
function(doc) {
    if (doc.type == 'country') {
      emit(doc.name, null);
    } else if (doc.cities) {    
    for (var i in doc.cities) {
          emit(doc.name, {_id: doc.cities[i]});
      } 
  }
}
```

**Documents:**

```
// Country
{
  "_id": "country.123",
  "name": "France",
  "type": "country",
  "cities": [
    "city.123"
    ]
}

// City
{
  "_id": "city.123",
  "name": "Paris",
  "type": "city",
}
```

---

**Update 1**

I tried removing the `else if` as Dominic suggested. Now nothing gets emitted unfortunately.

```
function(doc) {
    if (doc.type == 'country') {
      emit(doc.name, null);
          for (var i in doc.cities) {
            emit(doc.name, {_id: doc.cities[i]});
          } 
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want both code paths to be reached, do you need an `else if`?

Comment: Judging from your comment it seems that it is not necessary. Okay. I tried removing it, so that I first emit my countries and after that the for-function follows and gives me the cities. That was the plan but nothing gets emitted at all. Also judging from your comment, it must be possible right? I'm uncertain now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to emit the country document plus the linked city document?

```
function(doc) {
  if (doc.type == 'country') {
    emit(doc._id, doc)
    if (doc.cities) {    
      for (var i in doc.cities) {
        emit(doc.name, {_id: doc.cities[i]});
      } 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yep, this was it! Many thank. Sometimes this Map-Function stuff is hair-raising for me.